# Как в bootstrap сделать содержимое колонок одинаковой высоты?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox

Есть сетка `bootstrap 4` с 4 колонками. Как сделать так, чтобы контент внутри (покрашен с желтый цвет) при любом количестве содержимого был одинаковой высоты?
Для самих колонок есть отличное решение:

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Но, есть 2 проблемки: 
1 - внутри содержится ссылка, которая не `flex`;
2 - нужна обводка вокруг контента, НО без обводки самой картинки. Вот здесь у меня затык и я не знаю как решить.

**Код:**

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.row>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.task-box {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.task-box-inner {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-3 mb-5">
    <a class="task-box" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <div class="task-box-inner">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
        <div class="hour">posted 15 hours ago</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 mb-5">
    <a class="task-box" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <div class="task-box-inner">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
        <div class="hour">posted 15 hours ago</div>

      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 mb-5">
    <a class="task-box" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <div class="task-box-inner">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h4>
        <div class="hour">posted 15 hours ago</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 mb-5">
    <a class="task-box" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <div class="task-box-inner">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</h4>
        <div class="hour">posted 15 hours ago</div>

      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: можете добавить троеточие в конец текста :)

Comment: @Избыток сусликов давайте серьезнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если серьёзно то вот  так:

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
   border: 1px solid green;
   padding: 10px;
   align-items: stretch;
}
.task-box {
   background-color: yellow;  
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: stretch;
   height: 100%;
}
.task-box-inner {
   border:2px solid blue;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-3 mb-5">
            <a class="task-box" href="javascript:void(0);">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
     <div class="task-box-inner">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
      <div class="hour">posted 15 hours ago</div>
     </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-5">
            <a class="task-box" href="javascript:void(0);">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
     <div class="task-box-inner">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
      <div class="hour">posted 15 hours ago</div>

     </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-5">
            <a class="task-box" href="javascript:void(0);">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
     <div class="task-box-inner">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h4>
      <div class="hour">posted 15 hours ago</div>
     </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-5">
            <a class="task-box" href="javascript:void(0);">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
     <div class="task-box-inner">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud</h4>
      <div class="hour">posted 15 hours ago</div>

     </div>
            </a>
</div></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxy2h2hg/2/)

Comment: спасибо, но обратите внимание про проблемки, которые я указывал в описании (ведь стили у меня 1 в 1 с вашими)  `есть 2 проблемки: 1 - внутри содержится ссылка, которая не flex; 2 - нужна обводка вокруг контента, НО без обводки самой картинки. Вот здесь у меня затык и я не знаю как решить.`

Comment: А зачем вам в `a` куча блочных элементов, вы же в курсе что так нельзя?

Comment: поясните. а как можно? (я просто в стилях доп прописываю для ссылки тоже блочность) ну, заменю `span`ами, что принципиально изменится? Если это поможет решить задачу, то ок, но как?

Comment: нет не поможет, если вы хотите сделать что б при клике на один из col была ссылка то я покажу как если нужно, просто скажите.

Comment: ну смотрите, я же не просто так вверху код сбрасывал (если нужно - я из него фидл сделаю) - мне нужно, чтобы блоки с ссылками, которые закрашены желтым стали все одной высоты и контеет при этом без картинки был обрамлен бордером. Как обрамить весь контект и чтобы он был одинаковым - я знаю (добавить враппер),но вот когда картинка появляется - не могу придумать как сделать

Comment: дополнил ваш контент - фидл https://jsfiddle.net/pxy2h2hg/1/

Comment: Вам нужно что - то типа такого? https://jsfiddle.net/pxy2h2hg/2/

Comment: о, да, спасибо! Поправьте тогда ваш ответ выше - я его отмечу как готовый

Comment: Правил, и ссылку изменил на фидл :)